# optimizer_switch='index_condition_pushdown=off' in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, zabbix, postgresql-9.5

In MySQL there is an option named index_condition_pushdown which should be disabled to prevent [Zabbix slow queries](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/installation/known_issues#slow_mysql_queries).

I used PostgreSQL as Zabbix server DB. I'm getting this error in zabbix_server.log: `slow query: 62.356972 sec, "select distinct itemid from trends_uint where clock`

After that Zabbix was stopped with this log: `Zabbix Server stopped. Zabbix 3.4.9 (revision 80550).`

What should I do in PostgreSQL to prevent this error?